# Android open Contacts app (not choose a contact)

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to give the user possibility to open Contacts app from my app, so he can edit them, export etc. 
What I DON'T WANT is a contact picker where the user selects a contact. I need only to somehow open the Contacts app from my app. 
 How Can I do it ? Intent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet will do what you want .

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
     "com.android.contacts"
    ,"com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity");
startActivity(intent)
```